# interpolation between meshes

Tags: 3d, geometry, interpolation, mesh, morphing

I have three face meshes (person A neutral face and expression face and person B neutral face). I'm trying to create a new face mesh by using this simple transformation method 
*y’_i = y_i  + x’_i – x_i*  where 
*y_i* is person B neutral face vertices 
 *x’_i* is person A expression face vertices and 
 *x_i* is person B expression face vertices.
 To do this vertices should be correspondence. For example the left eye corner of person B corresponds to left eye corner of person A. I also have x,y,z coordinates of 26 landmarks points of each face. How to build this correspondence relationship among two meshes?

Comment: What platform / tools do you use? What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: i did the implementation using python. my problem is that i don't know how to implement this correspondence. It would be really helpful if you can give me tutorial or example to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "quick" answer to this question as it is a very deep problem. You might want to look at this book: http://books.google.com/books?id=SKTFw38ZS0UC - even if you just browse it online you will understand this is not a simple question with a simple answer.